# Python convert Dict with multiple keys to Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a Dict created from web data. I start with an empty Dict, like `d = {}`. I then loop through each web page and store each page of data in `d[i]` where i starts out as 0, `i = 0`. I then have a Dict with multiple keys/indexes (I'm not sure what the proper terminology is). I can enter `d[0]` and see the first page, `d[1]` to see the second page and so on. I am trying to union each of these keys/indexes so that I can convert this Dict to a Dataframe. The Dict looks like this:

```
{0:    Age (Days) Number of Items in Queue Number of Items in WIP  \
 3           4                        0                      2
 4           5                        0                      1
 5           6                        0                      2
 6           7                        0                      4
 7           9                        0                      1
 8          12                        0                      2
 9          14                        0                      4
 10         15                        0                      3
 11         17                        0                      1
 12         19                        0                      2
1:    Age (Days) Number of Items in Queue Number of Items in WIP  \
 3           0                        0                      1
 4           1                        0                      8
 5           2                        0                      3
 6           3                        0                      6
 7           4                        0                      1
 8           5                        0                      7
 9           9                        0                      9
 10         10                        0                      4
 11         11                        0                      3
 12         12                        0                      8
 13         13                        0                      2
 14         14                        0                      1
 15         15                        0                      5
 16         16                        0                      6
 17         17                        0                      1
 18         18                        0                      5
 19         19                        0                      7
 20         20                        0                      2}
```

I can't simply use `pd.DataFrame(d)`. I tried to use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list(d.values()))` but that didn't give the output I was expecting. I get the same output with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')`. The unwanted output is just listing each key/index and looks like this:

```
In [102]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
Out[102]:
                                                   0
0     Age (Days) Number of Items in Queue Number ...
1     Age (Days) Number of Items in Queue Number ...
2     Age (Days) Number of Items in Queue Number ...
```

I'm expecting the rows from `d[1]` to be added to `d[0]` and keep the same column names.

Comment: Try this: `df = pd.concat((d[k] for k in d.keys()), ignore_index=True)`

Comment: That was quick and perfect! Thank you! Want to post this as an answer and I'll mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can [concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them this way:

```
df = pd.concat(d.values(), ignore_index=True)
```